# Проверка формы PHP перед отправкой

Tags: php

Ребята такой вопрос - есть форма с множеством чекбоксов, так вот как сказать  php файлу что бы он отправлял форму если хотя бы ОДИН из чекбоксов был нажат?

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;"> <h1 class="normal  hairline ">Пн</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ПонедельникУтро" value="да"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ПонедельникДень" value="да"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ПонедельникВечер" value="да"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ПонедельникНочь" value="да"></td>
</tr>

<?php

{

$to = 'godofwar9325@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; 
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p><b>ПонедельникУтро:</b> '.$_POST['ПонедельникУтро'].'</p>
                        <p><b>ПонедельникДень:</b> '.$_POST['ПонедельникДень'].'</p> 
                         <p><b>ПонедельникВечер:</b> '.$_POST['ПонедельникВечер'].'</p> 
                         <p><b>ПонедельникНочь:</b> '.$_POST['ПонедельникНочь'].'</p>                          
                    </body>
                </html>'; 
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <uber-key.ru>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "<center><h2>Заявка отправлена, мы свяжемся с Вами в течении 15 минут.</h2>";





}?>
```

Comment: А где форма то?

Comment: И при чем тут PHP?

Comment: Что именно вы хотите? Чтобы письмо улетало только когда что-то выбрано, или форму нельзя было отправить, пока какой-то чекбокс не отмечен?

Comment: Если не использовать атрибут if то пустая форма улетает  на почту автоматом, а если перечислять все чекбоксы и их 25 то это не совсем удобно. Так вот как сказать так что - если один хотя бы чекбокс из 25 нажат то форма отправлялась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, такой код:

```
if (isset($_POST['ПонедельникУтро']) && $_POST['ПонедельникУтро'] == 'да') {
  echo("Выбран пункт про утро понедельника");
}
```

Показывает как можно проверить, что был выбран один из чекбоксов. Соответственно если добавить остальные и объединить их через ИЛИ (**||**) то можно достичь требуемого.

Но такой подход не очень правильный и ведет к увеличению энтропии вселенной в виде индуского кода.

Поэтому лучше переделать форму. Для этого следует посмотреть как ведет себя форма если у нее указать чекбоксы с одинаковым именем и разными значениями.

Например, вот так

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="ПонедельникУтро"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="time[]" value="ПонедельникДень"></td>
```

И посмотреть что приходит в PHP для разных вариантов заполнения формы.